# How to change 'echo $SHELL' to '\bin\zsh' on MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh

I have recently upgraded from Catlina to Big Sur and changed shell to zsh but when I echo  $SHELL it still shows /bin/bash how do I change this

[image]

Comment: Questions about _using and configuring_ UNIX systems belong at [unix.se], [Super User](https://superuser.com/), or in this case [apple.se]. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_ and tools exclusive to that purpose.

Comment: That said, the more important question is whether `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` has any output (if your shell is really zsh it should be an empty string). What `SHELL` contains is relatively unimportant, and you could change it with `SHELL=/bin/zsh` if you wanted to. (There may well be a `SHELL=/bin/bash` line somewhere in your dotfiles overriding what zsh sets itself).

Comment: BTW, if you want to figure out what's happening during zsh's initialization, `zsh -l -i -x` to log the commands it's running during setup is a good place to start. Unlike bash, where you need to change `PS4` to get the source filename and line number, zsh should include those in the trace log by default.

Comment: It's the `login` process that sets SHELL. Change your login shell using `chpass -s desired_shell_here` -- valid login shells are listed in /etc/shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the info on first comment
second comment - command `SHELL=/bin/zsh` is just for the session so it won't help if I quit the session and open again, and I am not sure where I should change to set that globally
third comment - sorry, I have no idea what all that as I'm not that technical to understand

Comment: @glennjackman thanks and worked after using 'chpass -s /bin/zsh'

Comment: Heh! I missed that the OP was showing terminal settings and not account settings in the screenshot. (Changing the shell in the account settings would have done the same change `chpass` does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either put a

```
SHELL==zsh
```

or

```
SHELL=$0:a
```

into your `~/.zshenv` (the difference between these two forms is explained below). This has several advantages:

- This file is only processed by zsh, interactive and non-interactive, so there is no risk that this setting is picked up by a different shell.
- By setting it as a shell variable and not an environment variable, child processes written in different shells (bash, ksh, sh, ...) can set the `SHELL` variable by themselves, if they like.
- By using the form `=zsh`, zsh expands the word *zsh* to the full path of the shell. This assumes that *zsh* is in your PATH, which is reasonable anyway.
- If you decide to go for the alternatie form, `$0:a`, instead of `=zsh`, you are assigning to `SHELL` the path of the *current* zsh. This makes a difference, if you have several zsh versions installed on your system, and want to make sure that `SHELL` is set to the one which is currently running.

Comment: Thank you @user1934428, I have accepted this as answer as it solved another issue I was facing with VSCode. After upgrade Mac OS to Big Sur my VSCode terminal window opens with Bash profile and I tried different ways to fix but end up opening VS Code from terminal (zsh) using `code .`. I believe that this has solved that issue and now I can open VSCode via Applications instead from terminal